# high load on RHEL5 XEN

Tags: linux, sendmail, rhel5

all I do is sending out bunch of emails and my server's load gets up to 900s, any ideas where to look?

Comment: How about some more detail? What load gets up to 900s?

Comment: i use latest RHEL5 w/ latest updates and on VM nothing but sendmail

Comment: what software are you using to actually initiate sending messages (sendmail is your MTA, but normally you've got a script/application handling your mailing). 

When you start a mailing - try running 'top' and looking for the processes in 'D' or 'R' - these are the processes actually driving the load, and may give us an idea what's actually going on.

(Also, how fast are you sending messages?)

Answer (score 1):

Load more detail needed before anyone can give you a proper answer.

What do you see in `top` when load average is that high?  Along the top line of top's output, what do the CPU stats look like?  A large amount of %us, or %wa?

How many e-mails are 'a bunch'?  Are they ones produced in a batch through some automated means?   What mail server software are you using on the server?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted you Xen configuration file, however my immediate guess is that the dom-u was given insufficient memory. Is this HVM or paravirt? Please provide some more information.

Loads like that usually mean I/O bound processes ... so some details about your network configuration (bridge / NAT) on dom-0 would also help.